# Can anyone tell me which caching tool is faster; AppFabric or Memcached?

Tags: memcached, appfabric

Can anyone tell me which caching tool is faster; AppFabric or Memcached? I got some vague answers on this question and that too for older versions. It would be great if someone can tell me the performance comparison on the recent versions of these two.

Comment: Hi Manu
The thing is, you cannot compare the speed and performance of AppFabric and Memcached directly without mentioning the platform.
AppFabric server basically runs on .NET platform while Memcached server runs on Java platform.Their clients can be of Java as well as .NET.AppFabric can be directly compared with other .NET distributed caches like [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) while Memcached can be compared with other Java caches like [Gigaspaces](http://www.gigaspaces.com/).